# java.util.List being stored out of order by Hibernate after .add(position, item)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jbpm

I have a JBPM casefile application using Java classes where a workflow has stages and the data gets persisted by Hibernate in an SQL Server database:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "WORKFLOW")
public class Workflow implements java.io.Serializable {

    @javax.persistence.OneToMany(cascade = {javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL})
    @org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private java.util.List<Stage> stages;

...
```

When I do a workflow.add(position, stage) the stage is added as the position+1 entry in the list (as expected).  Hibernate persists the java.util.List in our SQL Server database using a join table called WORKFLOW_STAGES with a workflow id and a stage id as its columns.  The list with the added element is always persisted as if it were the last element so even if the added element was added at position 1 a retrieved workflow has it at the end of the list.  I.e., if I were storing Integers instead of instances of Stage

```
original workflow.getStages() = 10, 5, 8
workflow.getStage().add(1, 4) => 10, 4, 5, 8 in memory but
when retrieved from the DB (using Hibernate) the new element has been moved to the end => 10, 5, 8, 4
```

The log looks WORKFLOW_STAGES is redone when the application persists so I am surprised it is not persisting the stages in the right order.

```
2021-11-16 12:26:37,253 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: delete from WORKFLOW_STAGES where Workflow_ID=?
2021-11-16 12:26:37,260 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: insert into WORKFLOW_STAGES (Workflow_ID, stages_ID) values (?, ?)
2021-11-16 12:26:37,261 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: insert into WORKFLOW_STAGES (Workflow_ID, stages_ID) values (?, ?)
2021-11-16 12:26:37,261 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: insert into WORKFLOW_STAGES (Workflow_ID, stages_ID) values (?, ?)
2021-11-16 12:26:37,262 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: insert into WORKFLOW_STAGES (Workflow_ID, stages_ID) values (?, ?)
2021-11-16 12:26:37,262 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: insert into WORKFLOW_STAGES (Workflow_ID, stages_ID) values (?, ?)
2021-11-16 12:26:37,262 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: insert into WORKFLOW_STAGES (Workflow_ID, stages_ID) values (?, ?)
2021-11-16 12:26:37,262 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: insert into WORKFLOW_STAGES (Workflow_ID, stages_ID) values (?, ?)
2021-11-16 12:26:37,262 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: insert into WORKFLOW_STAGES (Workflow_ID, stages_ID) values (?, ?)
2021-11-16 12:26:37,262 INFO  [stdout] (default task-164) Hibernate: insert into WORKFLOW_STAGES (Workflow_ID, stages_ID) values (?, ?)
```

How do I change my Hibernate tags to persist the List correctly, ie with the elements in the correct order after the add(position, element)?

Comment: I added a few comments but didn't notice the logs. Since in the logs it is deleting everything I would probably suspect something related to indexes on the database. What is the query that Hibernate is using to fetch `getStages()` I would start there checking whether the query actually returns what is desired if not it is probably something on the DB side

Comment: I am currently adding an explicit position field to Stage to orderBy it.  There was no explicit index field for Stage, but there was an index in the annotations that may have been mine (but I removed in favor of the position field in Stage).  I'll try to post the GET later when I do another trace. and thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a position field on Stage and the annotation @javax.persistence.OrderBy("position") to the definition of the List of stages.